# Unable to get Custom Plugin Options data

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I have created a custom courier tracking plugin and I need to save courier API in plugin option page. Here is my code

```
// create custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'dvs_tracking_menu_page');
function dvs_tracking_menu_page() {
    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('Courier Tracking Settings', 'Courier Tracking', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'dvs_tracking_menu_settings_page' , 'dashicons-location' );
    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'dvs_register_plugin_settings' );
}

function dvs_register_plugin_settings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'dvs-courier-settings-group', 'dvs_tcs_client_id' );
}

function dvs_tracking_menu_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'dvs-courier-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'dvs-courier-settings-group' ); ?>
    <h2>TCS Courier Settings</h2>
        <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
        <th scope="row" >Client ID</th>
        <td><input class="regular-text" placeholder="TCS Client ID" type="text" name="dvs_tcs_client_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('dvs_tcs_client_id') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>              
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
</div>
<?php }
```

This is how to get data

```
$dvs_tcs_client_id = get_option( 'dvs_tcs_client_id' );
```

It is working perfectly on my localhost and when I echo it displays the data but on a live website it displays nothing.

Please help

Comment: what dose this do?